# bash: creating an xls/csv

Tags: excel, bash, csv, xls

Found these answers but from these it is not clear to me how to **simply** create excel sheets.

These two marked as answer do create a sheet out of a given txt BUT the data in the two txt columns get inserted in a single column in the table created:
[How to convert a text file into excel in bash or perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45668255/how-to-convert-a-text-file-into-excel-in-bash-or-perl)

As if the tab-delimiter didnt work.

This answer does the same to me:
[How to write text file data into same cell of excel using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44772883/how-to-write-text-file-data-into-same-cell-of-excel-using-bash)

This one is too complicated for an amateur:
[Paste output into a CSV file in bash with paste command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43524670/paste-output-into-a-csv-file-in-bash-with-paste-command)

I just am not able to decipher and simplify the stuff.

This does the same - columns end up merged in the first one:

```
#!/bin/bash


while read value; do

   echo "$value"


done <tabulka.txt > test.csv
```

May I ask for a simple way to put data to an xls/csv? Im not really a bash expert, just an engineer forced to work with it. Thanks!

EDIT:
sample textfile as requested (tab as delimiter):

```
header1 header2

aaaa    1.0

bbbb    1.1

cccc    1.3
```

result:

[image]

Comment: I would have though you would need to add commas to the output? and so echo "$value,"

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your text file for clear understanding.

Comment: Sure. up above under EDIT.

Comment: Is there anything like sample syntax for filling certain cells in a sheet with certain data? I havent found anything like that so far regarding bash.

Comment: I beleive you need columns and rows... So you may need two loops.
Also, @RamanSailopal is right : you should separate values in your rows with commas or semi-colons.

Comment: You may also need to open it in a different way in excel : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9129197/1614410

Comment: Excel can certainly [import a tab-separated data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba); there's no reason to waste your time converting it to comma-separated data first.

Comment: Off course there is. It takes time to define it every time you import the data. Why wouldnt I let the computer do the work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so first step is to convert .txt to .csv. You don't provide your input data, so it is hard to see how you want to split it. If we assume, that your input file has fairly regular structure and you want simply replace " " to ",", you can do it like this. (But it would really be better if you clarified your question with sample data.):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read value; do

    echo "$value" | tr "\t" ","

done <tabulka.txt > test.csv
```

The second part is explained in the link you pasted - [Paste output into a CSV file in bash with paste command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43524670/paste-output-into-a-csv-file-in-bash-with-paste-command)

Excel can read the csv file ( as can libreoffice ). This works for me.

```
libreoffice --calc test.csv
```

If your file is in any way irregular it's not possible to guess, you have to show it.

Edit: I was writing my answer, when you posted your input. So I'm editing it to reflect, that you use tabs in the input.

Comment: Thanks! works just fine!                                                                                                                 So I guess there is no way of creating a table like: columnx, row y: "my arbitrary value" etc....

Comment: I must admit I don't know. At least not from top of my head. But it seems to me a bit complex task for a bash script. I'm sure it would be possible with perl...somehow.

Comment: Googled a lot w/o a success so you are probably right. The thing is that I am no programmer at all. Just an engineer so try to squeeze as much as possible from the tools that I have by hand. Thanks anyway!